# How to setup Google License Tester only can use Test Card in staging app?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, licensing, beta-testing

I have added my google account email into License Tester List to do Beta Testing. But when i published my app to production. My google playstore account still can use Test Card in production app. Its i miss out some configuration in google publish console, so can use Test Card in production?

It is possible only can use Test Card in Beta Testing?